# Content is not allowed in prolog in new activiy Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have started a new project and it has only one empty activity in Kotlin in Android Studio. I have not added or removed anything in the code. I have simply tried to run it and it is giving "Content is not allowed in prolog" in the build output. I don't know why is it showing this. It would be great help to find what is going wrong with the code.

Comment: What code are you referring to?  You didn't post any.

Comment: It is the default code that comes with the empty activity in Android studio.